# jquery resize parent child

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a div container with class embed and unique id. Inside the container div i have an embeded player code using either iframe or object. Ex:

```
<div class="embed" id"id21" style="width:480px; height:390px;">
<iframe width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Oe_3KgfcCXs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

When i resize the div container, i want the player inside it to resize as well. the embed code have the attributes of width and height. I did the following but unable to get it to work. I need to reference the container by it's id, so if i have another container with a different id, resizing should only take effect on the container being resized and non of the other containers.

```
$('.embed').live({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        var id = this.id;
        var height = $(id).height();
        var width = $(id).width();
        $(id).contents().attr({'width':width,'height':height});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.embed').live({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find("iframe").css(ui.size);
    }
});
```

Doesn´t this work?

Comment: Great one line answer. But what if the player is embeded using object and not iframe. We need to check for both iframe and object.

Comment: then use comma-seperation, .find("iframe, whateverdomelement")

Comment: ... or just `children()` if there is only one child element in the `.embed` element

Comment: yeah your right Šime but I like to have the control over what i control :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use CSS to control the `height` and `width` of the `iframe` in relative dimensions, say `%` then resizing the `div` will automatically resize the `iframe`:

```
iframe {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will only work if `.embed` has, as in your example, defined dimensions.

---

**Edited** to amend html, css and provide demo jQuery:

#### html:

```
<div class="embed" id="id21" style="width:480px; height:390px;">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Oe_3KgfcCXs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.embed {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    padding: 1em;
}

.embed:hover {
    border-color: #f90;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('.embed').resizable(
    {
        aspectRatio: 1.23,
        minHeight: 390,
        minWidth: 480
     });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/auLSx/).

Comment: Nice thinking. +1 for this. Your way means that i also have to change default iframe width height to 100% before this can work. Which means more code. Youtubes default is 480x390.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.embed').live({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).children()
            .width( $(this).width() )
            .height( $(this).height() );
    }
});
```